# Trigger to update a count based on another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a php project for managing employees.
i have two tables `employee` and `department` with the department number being a relation between the two. `department` has an attribute that contains a count of employees based on the deparment number.
So where i'm stuck is that i want the employee count to be automatically inserted, so what do you think i should do

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should really just calculate the number using a query.  But if you really want to store the number, then you need triggers for `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s.

Comment: I agree with Gordon. Seems really unnecessary to have this as its own column. You can use MySQL Count to get what you want in your queries instead. Its a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use (or have access to) a trigger, but want to abstract the logic, you could use a view ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html)).

So assuming the below data, and the idea of having the entire department table and the employee count dynamically calculated, you could have the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE
  `employees`
(
   `employeeID` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` VARCHAR(50),
   `department_number` INT
);

CREATE TABLE
  `departments`
(
  `department_number` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO 
   `departments`
(`department_number`, `name`)
VALUES
(1, 'Tech Department'),
(2, 'Admin Department');

INSERT INTO
  `employees`
(`name`, `department_number`)
VALUES
('John Doe', 1),
('Jane Doe', 1),
('Jimmy Doe', 2);
```

Then the query:

```
SELECT
    DepartmentTbl.*,
    DepartmentEmployeeTbl.employee_count
FROM
  `departments` AS DepartmentTbl
LEFT JOIN
  (
   SELECT
      `department_number`,
      COUNT(`employeeID`) AS `employee_count`
    FROM
      `employees`
    GROUP BY
      `department_number`
   ) AS DepartmentEmployeeTbl
   ON DepartmentTbl.department_number = DepartmentEmployeeTbl.department_number
```

Gives the result:

```
department_number | name              | employee_count
-------------------------------------------------------
1                 | Tech Department   | 2
2                 | Admin Department  | 1
```

SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e0b54/1

So to create this view, you could use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `departments_employee_count` AS
SELECT
        DepartmentTbl.*,
        DepartmentEmployeeTbl.employee_count
    FROM
      `departments` AS DepartmentTbl
    LEFT JOIN
      (
       SELECT
          `department_number`,
          COUNT(`employeeID`) AS `employee_count`
        FROM
          `employees`
        GROUP BY
          `department_number`
       ) AS DepartmentEmployeeTbl
       ON DepartmentTbl.department_number = DepartmentEmployeeTbl.department_number
```

Then you could call the view as:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `departments_employee_count`
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing and updating the value each time something is changed you should just calculate it when needed.
You can use [count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) to do it.

Example

```
SELECT department_number, count(*) FROM employee GROUP BY department_number
```